# NUnit Assert - Display full error message

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, assert, assertions

I have the following assertion:

```
Assert.AreEqual(AssertWelcomeMessage, loginPageModel.WelcomeMessage());
```

Each variables values are the following:

> AssertWelcomeMessage: Hello and welcome to our site! We really hope
>   you enjoy your visit here!
>
> loginPageModel.WelcomeMessage(): Hello and welcome to our site! We
>   really hope you enjoy your \n visit here!

So the test fails, ok.

When I get the log I see the following:

> Expected: "...really hope you enjoy your visit here!"
>
> But was: "...really hope you enjoy your \n visit here!"

The question is: How can I see the full sentence?

Comment: You can't as that is how the developer wrote their code. Don't need to see the full sentence anyway. They showed you where the difference is. There was a line break `\n` in the value returned from `loginPageModel.WelcomeMessage()`. They would only show you a portion of where they found the difference as showing all of a potentially huge string may cause exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't as that is how the developer wrote their code.

Don't need to see the full sentence anyway. They showed you where the difference is. There was a line break (`\n`) in the value returned from `loginPageModel.WelcomeMessage()`.

This is the important information needed in the test report. The full sentence is of no real value to why the test failed. The fact that it was not what was expected is the real value of the message.

They would only show you a portion of where they found the difference as showing all of a potentially huge string may cause exceptions.

Comment: As a minor addition: if you use `Assert.That` with an `EqualConstraint`, you can add the modifier `.NoClip` and see the entire string. It's rather useless, but I have used it when debugging NUnit itself.

Comment: I've actually found this useful before, where tests asserted that some external tool did the right thing by checking its output. But when the tool went wrong the error message from the tool is truncated without `NoClip`